# Retrieving the physical addresses of all the pages of a virtual memory buffer

Tags: linux, memory-management, linux-kernel

I am currently trying to find the physical addresses of all the pages linked to a virtual buffer.

For example if I allocate a buffer of 8kb in virtual memory and that in terms of physical memory it allocates me 2 pages (in the case where the pages are 4kb and everything goes well), I would like to find the physical address of these 2 pages. As if I had allocated them with get_free_pages.

For that I realized this little piece of code by looking at the functions which was at my disposal in the kernel :

```
void *vbuffer;
struct page *page_list;
unsigned long current_page_addr;

/* Allocate virtual memory buffer */
vbuffer = vmalloc(size);

/* Get pages list from the previously allocated virtual buffer */
page_list = vmalloc_to_page(vbuffer);

do {

    current_page_addr = page_to_phys(page_list);
    page_list = page_list->next;

} while(page_list != NULL);
```

My question is therefore to know if my code is correct and actually allows me to retrieve my physical addresses of the pages in my current_page_addr variable.
Also if I am using the right way or if there is a better way, thank you.

Comment: Have you tried running this? Does it crash or show kernel errors?

Comment: Typically Stack Overflow isn't a good place for asking for code reviews. Generally, you should formulate these posts as a question. For instance, if you ran this and had an error, include the error and ask for help. If no error, you can ask for alternative/better ways of doing what you're trying to do.

Comment: As for your code, there's one thing that I'm not sure will work, but you'll report back on if there's an error. I'm not sure if the `page_list` is iterated with `->next` or if you need to use something like `page_list->lru->next` or use a macro like `list_next_entry(page, lru)`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think the pages for the `vmalloc`ed region are in a list.  `vmalloc_to_page` returns the page corresponding to a virtual address mapped in the vmalloc region, if the page exists. So to find the pages corresponding to the memory allocated by `vmalloc` or `vzalloc`, start with the returned address for the first page, and increment the address by `PAGE_SIZE` for each subsequent page.

```
void *vbuffer;
struct page *page;
unsigned long current_page_addr;

/* Allocate virtual memory buffer */
vbuffer = vmalloc(size);
if (vbuffer == NULL) {
    goto error;
}

for (size_t offset = 0; offset < size; offset += PAGE_SIZE) {
    page = vmalloc_to_page(vbuffer + offset);
    current_page_addr = page_to_phys(page);
}
```